# Making custom vertical scrollbar in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to make a custom vertical scrollbar component (or plugin) that will work on grid. 
Which Ext component is best to extend for this ? 
Is there a scrollbar component or plugin already in ExtJs library which I can extend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that it is ok solution to use panel with Ext.slider vertically oriented and some buttons.